# Can't call the time data in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have this csv data below:

```
2015-01-02,02:29:45 PM,Red
2015-01-02,05:16:15 PM,Red
2015-01-02,05:48:46 PM,Blue
2015-01-02,03:18:34 PM,Blue
2015-01-02,05:22:55 PM,Red
2015-01-02,03:25:45 PM,Blue
2015-01-02,04:23:16 PM,Red
```

I am trying to plot this data into a graph using matplotlib
where x-axis = Date, y-axis = time, values = either red or blue colored points
However, I am getting this error when trying to call the time column:

```
time = df('Time')
print (time.head())
**DataFrame' object is not callable**
```

But if I call the date column, it works fine:

```
date = df['Date']
print (date.head())

0   2015-01-02
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-02
3   2015-01-02
4   2015-01-02
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Maybe put in the question your code to plot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
time = df['Time']
```

Use the `[]` instead of `()` when accessing columns in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: amazing. Neophyte here. Thanks. :)